Syntax error: unexpected 'SELECT' in a simple query
I have a problem with a very simple piece of code, and I am hoping someone can tell me where I have gone wrong - the code is
DECLARE AnalysisDate DATE := '2024-06-27';
SELECT TO_VARCHAR(:AnalysisDate, 'YYYYMMDD');

I get tis error:

Syntax error: unexpected 'SELECT'.

My ultimate goal is to pass a date value into a procedure and have it form part of a file path.

In Snowflake, you need to use the SET command to assign a value to a variable SET AnalysisDate = '2024-06-27'; SELECT TO_CHAR($AnalysisDate, 'YYYYMMDD') AS FormattedDate;

Or, if you’re trying to write a SQL scripting block, you need a BEGIN…END round your SELECT

Hi @NickW, when I encapsulate the SELECT statement with BEGIN and END, the query returns null

To be accurate , it’s the anonymous block returning null, not the query. If you want the block to return something then you need to code this explicitly - have a look at the SQL Scripting documentation
